# Compositor output as texture in Cycles material? Better in realtime?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

If there any way to use Node Compositor output result as texture or image in Cycles material/shader?   Better in realtime?
Or use Compositor nodes in Material Node Editor?
May be any Addon to automate something?

Comment: No there is no way to use the compositor output or nodes directly, you would need to generate an image file (or an image sequence) and use that for your material textures. What are you trying to do?

Comment: My own Addon for that:) In general I need a lot of nodes of Compositor in Cycles for rich textures setup for PBR in realtime based on single RGB input from photogrammetry source. And I like to see immediately the result of RGB processing in Cycles Render viewport on highpoly photogrammetry mesh. Because UV on it is extremely fragmented I have to see changes on model, not on texture. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible in 2023? Or do i still need to render the compositor result to use it? I have made a mask on a video in the masking tab. I want to use it in a plane as video texture on a 3d scene. Thanks!